# MySql return 'I FOUND IT' string if found in table

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I am making a small MySQL query, I am a little stumped on how to form it.

I am just trying to return a string that is NOT in the database if a result is found in the database.

an example being:

```
{-----table-----}
|(id)    (Value)|
|1        Bob   |
|2        Jason |
|3        Alex  |
|4        Tony  |
{---------------}
```

The query would work something like

```
SELECT IF((SELECT Value FROM table WHERE (Value = 'Jason')),'I FOUND HIM','HE IS MISSING!')
```

The output would then be 'I FOUND HIM'

```
SELECT IF((SELECT Value FROM table WHERE (Value = 'Jerry')),'I FOUND HIM','HE IS MISSING!')
```

The output would then be 'HE IS MISSING!'

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you using your VERY DRAMATIC SQL! for?

Comment: postfix transport map w/ aliases.  If the address is found locally then the transport should be local. I didn't want to add an entire column just to store the same value over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use a count

```
SELECT IF((SELECT count(Value) FROM table WHERE (Value = 'Jerry')) > 0 ,'I FOUND HIM','HE IS MISSING!')
```

Comment: That's the ticket. So simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT Value FROM [Table] WHERE Value = 'Jerry')
BEGIN PRINT 'I FOUND HIM' END
ELSE
BEGIN PRINT 'HE IS MISSING') END
```